# What are the areas of a screen on a mobile called, which can be easily reached when holding the phone with one hand?

Tags: mobile, terminology

I'm trying to research the issue, and don't have a name for these locations.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You may be referring to **[thumb zones](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/09/the-thumb-zone-designing-for-mobile-users/)**.

[image]

[From LukeW](https://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1927):

> In his analysis of 1,333 observations of smartphones in use, Steven Hoober found about 75% of people rely on their thumb and 49% rely on a one-handed grip to get things done on their phones. On large screens (over four inches) those kinds of behaviors can stretch people’s thumbs well past their comfort zone as they try to reach controls positioned at the top of their device.

Comment: Cool.  That's the phenomena I'm interested in. And that sounds like a logical name for it.

Comment: I believe this graphic is a bit outdated. I have Samsung S9 and not the smallest of hands but my thumb only really covers the lower 2/3 of the phone. I **can** shift the phone in my palm to be able to reach the top but I avoid it to the point I'd rather just not interact with the app/website that requires me to do it.

Comment: @Maurycy you can shift the phone, but then you risk dropping it... (this doesn't contradict your point)

Comment: Reading around this issue, its clearly complex, and given that phones have got a lot bigger over the last 10 years, it's been a rapidly moving ball.

Comment: @Maurycy Isn't that your self-inflicted problem from buying a phone that is completely impractical?

Comment: @pipe The size of the natural/stretching/hard regions isn't really relevant to the question.

Comment: @chepner So why is the comment about the S9 relevant?

Comment: @pipe Was that meant to be a jab? I referred to S9 because it's a flagship so theoretically should represent a fairly large market share and is a phone I currently own, which allowed me to just pick it up, see how far I can reach with my thumb and how comfortably and notice that it doesn't match the image I see - I am unable to comfortably reach the top 1/3. This made me post the comment implying that sizes and proportions of phones have changed since the image was made  and might be outdated. This completely ignoring the abhorrent rounded edges which requires using a case to not mistap.

Comment: @Maurycy Yep, it was a jab. I think a handheld gadget that you can't actually reach is ridiculous, and I had to search for some time to find a usable phone last time I replaced mine. Obviously I'm in the minority of wanting to use my phone with one hand.

Comment: @pipe It's a fair but one-dimensional criticism - I care less about being able to reach the whole phone with one finger and more about increasing the chances of hitting the letters I try to type; having a smooth and non-laggy experience; having access to security updates. It's an acceptable trade-off for me.I am sure I could a phone that on top of those things would also allow me to reach the whole phone with my thumb, but that's not something that bothers me.

Comment: @Maurycy considering the graphic was taken from an article posted in 2016, of course it's "a bit" outdated... following [a similar article in 2014](https://usabilla.com/blog/designing-thumbs-thumb-zone/), it's possibly based on an iPhone 4 with *a 3.5 inch screen*...

Answer (score 6):

To complement [@MikeM's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/133490/64458): iOS has a function called [Reachability](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/touch-iph77bcdd132/13.0/ios/13.0#iph145eba8e9) which brings 'unreachable' areas into the 'reachable' area.

> #### Turn on and use Reachability
>
> When you use an iPhone that supports Reachability in Portrait orientation, you can bring items at the top of the screen down to the lower half of the screen.

Comment: For me (iPhone 11) it brings the top of the screen down to the50% mark, which is right at the limit of being reachable for me. I have to say I’ve not really noticed before just how much of my phone screen is out of reach of just one thumb

Comment: Android also has a feature called "One-Handed Mode" which puts the entire UI into a smaller rectangle on your screen. https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/one-hand-mode/